# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Array'

Tags: c#

I'm watching a VS 2010 tutorial video and he goes like this:

```
public static ArrayList GetRoomByType(string roomType)
```

When I try to do it in my VS 2013, the ArrayList doesn't seem to work, I tried making it:

```
public static Array GetRoomByType(string roomType)
```

and it goes fine, but when he do:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

of course I'll go:

```
Array list = new Array();
```

But then again the error

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Array

I read some question regarding this stuff in other post and it doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: Add `using System.Collections;` at the top of the document you're working with and use ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I add what you said and the ArrayList in the Public static do work! But the  ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); says the namespace could not be found. I wonder that I would create a namespace. But in the video, he did not.

Comment: You don't have to have a namespace. What exactly does it say?

Comment: Nope! I just miss-capital the ArrayList to Arraylist. But hey thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you face a similar problem in the future: substituting type with another one with a similar name isn't a vary good idea. If VS doesn't recognise a built-in type, just find it in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com). At the top of the corresponding article there will be the following section:

Namespace:  [namespace]

Assembly:  [assembly]

Adding `using [namespace];` will be enough in some cases, in others you'll also have to add a reference to the assembly.

Comment: Since he's using VS you might want to mention that it'll often find the namespace for you with `Shift-Alt-F10` or that dumb little box that shows up. As long as the assembly in question is referenced, of course.